# The multi-part identifier "tblOrders.Weight" and "tblOrders.Variety" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

```
UPDATE
  Inventory
SET
  Quantity = Inventory.Quantity - tblOrders.Quantity
WHERE
  Inventory.Weight = tblOrders.Weight
  AND Inventory.Variety = tblOrders.Variety
```

I wanted to update my Inventory table using this query but it's not accepting my code. Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: Since `tblOrders` doesn't exist in your query thats where the error is coming from. How should it be included in the query? With a join?

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause of the error** - You are trying to access a column in the `tblOrders` table (or an alias) which wasn't referenced in the query.

**Solution** - Since the actual schema is not available in the question, you could try something like this

```
UPDATE Inventory
SET Quantity = Inventory.Quantity - tblOrders.Quantity
FROM Inventory I
JOIN Orders tblOrders
    ON I.Id = tblOrders.Id
WHERE I.Weight = tblOrders.Weight
  AND I.Variety = tblOrders.Variety
```